# How to deployment shopify app Template php on aws for test

Tags: reactjs, laravel, amazon-ec2, shopify-template

I would like to know how your deployment process was in aws since I made an application based on React and Laravel but I have not been successful in publishing the application to send it to Shopify, in our development environment it works perfectly, but at Trying to make the connection on our EC2 instance is unsuccessful.

Do you have a guide that can give us visibility to the process.

I would greatly appreciate your support.

Test app on aws ec2 instance for Shopify test process